# play display from MacBook to projector connected to mac pro

Tags: display, macos, airplay

I've got a projector connected to my MacPro. Now I would like to be able to mirror the screen from my MacBook(!) to this projector.

Is this possible? Seems like an use case for AirPlay, but I am new to the Mac-World and do not find a way to do this. Thx!

Comment: How is the projector attached to the MacBook?

Comment: it isn't ;) Thats the point! I would like to stream from my MacBook to the projector via the MacPro without attaching it directly to the MacBook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install software like [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) on the Mac Pro.

Then your MacBook (assuming it can airplay to other displays) will see the Reflector advertisement and push the MacBook screen to the window on the Mac Pro.

Once that's set - set the Mac Pro to direct the Reflector 2 window to full screen on the projector.

Worst case, you'd need software like AirParrot on the MacBook if it's not new enough to AirPlay to a remote screen from the OS level and hardware.

Comment: works like a charm. thx!